# Frequency of $3$ of a kind

Tags: combinations

My lecture slide says the number of ways of choosing a $3$ of a kind card-hand is (assume we are finding $5$-card hands from a standard deck of cards) $ c(4,3)\times \ c(13,1) \times\ c(48,2) $. But I found a different answer in [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability). Could somebody please tell me which one is correct?

Comment: The slide formula includes full houses, wiki doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Both formulae start with ${13 \choose 1}{4 \choose 3}$ for picking a kind and 3 suits. Then, your lecture slides have the factor ${48 \choose 2}$ for picking just any 2 of the 48 cards not of the chosen kind. On the other hand, the wikipedia formula has instead of this 3rd factor ${12 \choose 2}{4 \choose 1}^2$ for picking 2 cards of any combination of suits but *differing in kind*, for else that would score higher at poker. So it seems the latter is more exacting and accurate in its definition of "3 of a kind".

Comment: In particular, the answer $\binom{4}{3}\binom{13}{1}\binom{48}{2}$ allows for the possibility of a full house.